# Can I create a service in fastapi using an imported function from another .py file?

Tags: python, function, service, fastapi

I have written some functions with python in separate files. My task is to transform these functions into services using fastAPI and the services should return a JSON that says if the operation is executed correctly or not (a code and a message).

For example, I have a file `sum.py` and inside there's a function that sums two numbers and returns the result:

```
def sum_of_two_numbers(a,b):
    tot = a+b
    return tot
```

Let's say I want to create a service using fastAPI, do you know if I can import `sum_of_two_numbers` from `sum` and use [TestClient](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/testing/) to complete this task without modyfing the code or re-writing it?

In this example the function is short, but have in mind my functions are different. I needed one month to write them all and make the connection to the Oracle db. While reading the documentation of fastAPI, I understood I should modify all the syntax to adapt it for fastAPI.

So, in short can I do this with fastAPI by simply importing the functions and without changing all the functions syntax? Or do you know if is there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a basic fastapi app structure you often have something like this:

Example taken from  [Bastien-BO/fastapi-RBAC-microservice](https://github.com/Bastien-BO/fastapi-RBAC-microservice), inspired by [Kludex/fastapi-microservices](https://github.com/Kludex/fastapi-microservices) and  [tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql](https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql/)

```
.
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── dependencies.py
│   └── routers
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── items.py
│   │   └── users.py
│   └── models
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── items.py
│   │   └── users.py
│   └── schemas
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── items.py
│   │   └── users.py
│   └── internal
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── crud
|   |   |   └── user.py
|   |   |   └── item.py
```

Often in your internal files you have functions or classes that you can serve with routes.

Example of a user route with internal db function call:

```py
# app/routers/users.py
from app.internal.crud.user import crud_user

@router.get("/", response_model=List[UserOut])
async def read_users(offset: int = 0, limit: int = 100, session: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    users = crud_user.get_multi(session, offset=offset, limit=limit)
    return users
```

```py
# app/internal/crud/user.py

def crud_user():
    #do db stuff here
```

In this example, your `sum_of_two_numbers` function would be in the internal folder and you would wrap it in a route like what is done in read_users.

You should follow the [user guide](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/) or the [advanced user guide](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/) (fit better to your need i believe) from fastapi official doc. Also take a look at tiangolo (fastapi creator) [Base Project Generator](https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql/). You will have a good example on how to create a strong base for your API.